# Adding Push Notification to existing app - resubmission required?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I've an app already on app store with code to handle push notifications. However, it was not configured in Apple Development Portal during my previous submission.

Now that it has been enabled, do I need to resign and resubmit the app? Tried testing it myself but It wasn't working and I'm not sure if it's something that I did wrongly.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more that you have to do in code such as handling when a user successfully registers for push notifications so you will need a resubmit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd need to sign the app with a provision that carries the appropriate entitlements, and resubmit.